# How must have Liu Xin calculated $\pi$?

Tags: soft-question, approximation, math-history, pi

I know there won't be a definite answer to this question because of a lack of required historical evidence but there is so much we know of Liu Xin and of that time period. In that time, to get to an approximation 3.154 was a phenomenal feat.

To this day, no one knows how Liu Xin did it but we can speculate, can't we?

According to Science and Civilisation in China, Volume 3: Mathematics and the Sciences of the Heavens and the Earth
by **Joseph Needham**, we do not know how Liu Xin (Liu Hsin) arrived at this approximation for $\pi$

On page $100$ of the book, Needham writes the following:
[image: xin]

If you can find the records of how he did it, that would be great. But I ask this soft-question so that someone can correctly guess how it was done. I'm sure someone will formulate the same method. Liu Xin was also human :)

Comment: When did Liu Xin live ? I guess long before Archimedes because Archimedes already calculated $\pi$ much more precisely.

Comment: @Peter No, he was a contemporary to Augustus, so 200 years after Archimedes' death.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Liu Xin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Xin) claims that: "Liu Xin was the first to give a geometrical figure which implies a more accurate value of pi at 3.1457, although the exact method he used to reach this figure is unknown." Some references are mentioned there, including Needham. The approximation in the Wikipedia article is different from the one mentioned in your post. The edition of Needham's book [on Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=jfQ9E0u4pLAC&pg=PA100) contains the same figure as the post. Ido not know whether there are other editions.

Comment: The [talk page of that Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Liu_Xin) mentions 3.1547. I will also add a link to the [current revision of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Liu_Xin&oldid=746092051), in case it changes.

Comment: @MartinSleziak : Wow, that's an even better approximation. I wonder where that popped out of.

Comment: Maybe a question for https://hsm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I thought it worth adding this to https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Approximations_of_%CF%80&type=revision&diff=853699737&oldid=852855564

Comment: Could it be that Liu Xin had no theory about π, but simply based his figures on measurements?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Are you sure? I think I was asking for the core algorithm for estimating pi developed by Liu Xin.

Comment: @PJTraill Well, that would make this question terribly dumb, wouldn't it.

Comment: @Nick: It would be a little unfortunate, I suppose! But one has to bear the possibility in mind.

Comment: @PJTraill I wish atleast your speculation could be accompanied by the weight of some reference citation.